# Changing my imag src using ajax getting the location from db

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, image

How can I change the img src of the img using the ajax. I have the location save in my database and I want to set the img src from the value of something `data[0]['patient_photo']` I have the html of like this from my image :

```
<img id="checkup_pic" src="">
```

Here is my ajax code :

```
success: function(data) {
        $('#valfname').text(data[0]['patient_fname']);
        $('#valmname').text(data[0]['patient_mname']);
        $('#vallname').text(data[0]['patient_lname']);
        $('#valad').text(data[0]['patient_address']);
        $('#valcont').text(data[0]['patient_contact_info']);
        $('#valsex').text(data[0]['patient_sex']);
        $('#valcvilstat').text(data[0]['patient_civil_status']);
        $('#valbday').text(data[0]['patient_bday']);
        $('#valage').text(data[0]['patient_age']);
        $('#valheight').text(data[0]['patient_height']);
        $('#valweight').text(data[0]['patient_weight']);

        $('#checkup_pic').attr("src","");
```

Comment: `$('#checkup_pic').attr("src", data[0]['patient_photo']);` ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use **attr** property of jquery and pass your **src** in the value.

**Try below code:**

```
$('#checkup_pic').attr("src",data[0]['patient_photo']);
```

Comment: Great to help keep helping :)

Answer (score 6):

You could use jQuery functions **[`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)** or **[`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)** to set property to the DOM elements :

> **prop() :** Set one or more properties for the set of matched elements.
>
> **attr() :**  Set one or more attributes for the set of matched elements.

So you need just to pass the source of your image `data[0]['patient_photo']` to the `src` attribute of your `img` tag identified by `#checkup_pic`, like :

```
$('#checkup_pic').prop("src", data[0]['patient_photo']);
//Or
$('#checkup_pic').attr("src", data[0]['patient_photo']);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url, // url of your file from your data is being fetched like index.php
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
        $("#checkup_pic").attr('src', data[0]['patient_photo']);
    }
})
```